# What Might Cause Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp to Automatically Reboot to OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, boot-camp, reboot

### Problem

I have a 27" iMac with a 1TB Fusion Drive. I have Bootcamp running with Windows 8.1 installed on a partition. When I boot into Windows and leave the computer idle, I come back to find it has restarted and booted to the OSX partition automatically.

Admittedly, I don't use the Windows partition very often, but when I do use it I tend to be gaming. I will play a few hours and leave the PC idle while I take a break. I come back hours later, or sometimes the next morning and find the PC sitting at the OSX login screen.

I know Windows 8.1 automatically reboots to install updates on occasion, but last night I was doing some maintenance on the Windows partition and did all available Windows updates/Software updates. I then rebooted an additional time and began a CCleaner Scan.

I left the PC and went to bed. This AM I come to my desk and it is sitting on the OSX login screen again.

### Question

What things might cause something like this?

**Things I have checked:**

1. Power Options - There seems to be no option that could cause an automatic reboot if left idle
2. Automatic Updates - While this can cause a reboot when left idle, I
   have tested this theory by running all available updates and
   performing reboots before leaving the PC idle. Still a possibility,
   I suppose, but it's becoming less likely.
3. Crashing programs - I have no errors in the Event Viewer or startup
   warnings after booting back into Windows

I greatly appreciate any tips/advice you may have.

Aaron

Comment: You could try sitting in front of your computer with your hands at your sides and waiting for it to happen. Or possibly watching it with a video camera.

Comment: Have you checked `event viewer` on the windows install to see why/if it's shutting down?

Comment: I came back to the computer yesterday afternoon to check my CCleaner and it came back from hibernate. I started following Canadian Luke's suggestions and the PC suddenly crashed and rebooted. "Your system ran into a problem and needs to restart." The error information it provided was just "system_thread_exception_not_handled". After rebooting and turning off hibernation support, the issue appears to be resolved. I left it all night and checked it again this AM and it was still in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known issues about the Sleep Mode or Hibernate mode causing it to "reboot". Check the following:

1. In the Administrative Command Prompt (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), type `powercfg -h off` to disable Hibernation support
2. In the Power Settings (<kbd>Windows key</kbd>, type `power` and choose the Control Panel item), make sure that sleep mode is completely disabled for being idle. See the Windows 7 screenshot below for reference.

[image]

If it still does the OSX booting automatically, then there is definitely something else wrong.

Comment: Disabling hibernation support seems to have resolved it. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @Aaron No problem :) Happy to help